# Windows batch Nested for loop issue

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to read a file in outer loop line by line, take this value and use it in inner loop. But currently I am able to read first line from this file and do some required processing in inner loop but outer loop runs only once.

Why does the outer loop run only once?

myfile.txt contains:

AWC00201
AWC00202
AWC00203
DDDD

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%D in (myfile.txt) do (  
echo %D%
S:
cd \@vantage\AFG\AWC\AWCU\simulation\WRO_Regression_results\%%D
echo %%D
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d') DO (
echo After Nested For
echo %%D
SET test=%%D
SET b=%%i
GOTO found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto done
:found
echo %D%
echo Most recent subfolder: %b%
cd %b%
echo %%D
find /c "O K" tooling.report
echo %D%
if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound
echo found
goto done
:notfound
echo notfound
goto done
:done
echo %D%
echo now go up
echo !test!
echo %test%
)
pause
```

I am getting following output:

```
ECHO is off.
AWC00201
After Nested For
AWC00201
ECHO is off.
Most recent subfolder: 20141103_170658_wro_awc
%D
____________ TOOLING.REPORT:  0
ECHO is off.
notfound
ECHO is off.
now go up
AWC00201
AWC00201
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: Can't you use powershell? It runs on all modern Windows OS and makes these things much more elegant.

Comment: Sounds good but only due to lack of time I need to finish this task asap. but nice idea thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has one big problem and one thing to change

The problem is that it is not possible to use `goto` while inside a `for` loop and keep the loop iterating. `goto` cancels the `for` looping.

The thing to change is your use of variables. You have the information you need inside the `for` replaceable parameters. Use them. Move the value to a variable when the replaceable parameters does not offer what you need, but this is not the case

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%D in (myfile.txt) do (

    cd /d "s:\@vantage\AFG\AWC\AWCU\simulation\WRO_Regression_results\%%D"
    for /d %%a in (.) do echo Current folder is "%%~fa"

    set "file="
    FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /o-d 2 >nul ') DO if not defined file (
        set "file=1"
        echo subfolder found : %%i
        find /c "O K" ".\%%i\tooling.report" >nul 2>nul 
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo O K found 
        ) else (
            echo O K not found or file does not exist
        )
    )
    if not defined file (
        echo subfolder not found
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: Probably you are right, I will give it a try and let you know about results. Thank you.